# What would you recommend to do simple 2D Graphics?

Tags: graphics, animation

I want to build a program that will (as part of what it's doing) display lines organically growing and interacting horizontally across the screen.  Here's a sample image, just imagine the lines sprouting from the left and growing to the right:

[image: Line Example]

The lines would look like the lines used on [Google Maps Transit Overlay](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=nyc&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=54.401733,114.169922&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=New+York&ll=40.734056,-73.985968&spn=0.051445,0.111494&t=p&z=14&lci=transit) or [OnNYTurf](http://www.onnyturf.com/subway/)'s transit pages.

It's a personal project, so I'm open to just about any language and library combination.  But I don't know where to start.  What have you used in the past to create graphics that are similar to this?  What would you recommend?   I want it to run on Windows without any extras needed (.Net is fine), and it doesn't have to run elsewhere.  I needs to run as an actual program, not javascript in the browser.

There's obviously no 'right' answer to this, but the purpose isn't to start an argument about X better than Y but rather just find a list of graphics toolkits that do simple 2D graphics that people recommend because of their ease of use or community or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) may be just the tool for you.

Comment: I've looked at Processing and gone through some tutorials, but it seems it's more graphics oriented as an end, as opposed to a feature.  What I mean is, I couldn't find a way to embed it as a library in a larger program, and have it take orders on what to draw.  The majority of the program will *not* be graphics oriented.  It seems I could try and write the whole thing in Processing but that'd be the wrong tool I think.

Comment: @Tom, it looks like you can embed a Processing panel in another application. See: http://dev.processing.org/reference/core/javadoc/processing/core/PApplet.html

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there are many ways to tackle this problem.  Me personally, being it is a windows based project, I would go with the .NET based implementation utilizing WPF.  There are tutorials on how to use the 2D drawing feature out there ( http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html for one )  Again, there is no right answer here.  I might also pick some new technology and let your project be a mechanism to learn something new, providing you do not have a looming deadline.

Comment: I knew there'd be some way to draw with WPF - but having to fight that hard against WPF just to draw lines makes me pretty nervous of investing in it.  I'm cool with learning something new, I just wanted recommendations on *what* =)